# What is the best way to change drawable of all item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Let say I have my view that I use it as a toggle button. When user clicks it, I change the background via `setBackgroundResource()`. The number of list is around 15 items and `ListView` can show only around 7 items on screen.

At first, I try to use `ListView.getChildAt(position)` but when position is more than 7 it returns `NullPointer`. eventhough `ListView.getCount()` returns 15. But that's make sense because it show only visible child.

Then I solve it by loop through all Data that binds to this `Adapter`, change the boolean value, and call `notifyDataSetChange()`

So the number of loop will be 15 for update data + 7 show visible view.

The best way should be 15 and that's done.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget your child index. You should just toggle some type of flag in your adapter.

Then when your getView method is called again it will redraw your list.

i.e.:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private boolean useBackgroundTwo = false;

   .. constructor ..

   @Override
   public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ...


       ...


       View background = findViewById(...);

       int backgroundResource = R.drawable.one;
       if(useBackgroundTwo){
            backgroundResource = R.drawable.two;
       }
       background.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);



       ....
   }

    public void useNewBackground(){
       this.useBackgroundTwo = true;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void useOldBackground(){
       this.useBackgroundTwo = false;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Then in your activity code:

```
((YourAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).useNewBackground();
```

Taking it further, you could use an enum instead of a boolean and have multiple methods `setBackgroundGreen()`, `setBackgroundRed()` or you could pass in the drawable you want to use `setItemBackground(R.drawable.one);` The choice is yours.

[Api: Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

Comment: Thank, that enlightens me.